# Google spreadsheet API doesn't work on api/POST on Vercel but works on local

Tags: google-sheets, next.js, vercel

Next.js app works fine on local and also on data fetching (getStaticProps) on vercel. However, post data form submission via pages/api/add is not working

Getting this error:

> FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
> failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS
> connection was established

Confirm that credentials generated from Google API are added as env variables and are correct without any typo.

With some debugging found that

- Max execution limit is not a problem when I pass hardcoded values to getStaticProps and it gets inserted (on vercel and local)
- POST data to goolesheets via api/add is not working (I've tried npm-google-spreadsheet and also official googleapis npm packages)

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Not yet resolved, I've also asked it in the Next.js forum here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30789 Still waiting for an answer and others had the same issue too.